# Flexslider not working in wordpress site after plugin update

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

The [website in question](http://formacaoformadores.info/) uses the following theme : [adapt](http://www.wpexplorer.com/adapt-free-responsive-wordpress-theme/) Wordpress theme, which features a slider that worked perfectly fine . Until yesterday, it stopped working. I deactivated all the plugins to try to find if it helped, but it didn't. Can you try to help me find out what is wrong?

By the source code, I can see that the images that were supposed to appear on the slider are being fetched, but the slider is failing to load

Comment: Looking at your source, I do not see any type of JS that would perform the slide action.

Comment: I looked into functions.php, and there are at least 7 wp_enqueue_script instructions. What could cause that those files are not being loaded?

Comment: maybe reload WP & theme?

Comment: I actually enabled other theme and then enabled the previous theme to see if it had any effect. It didn't.

what do you mean by reloading wordpress ? and theme?

Comment: If you go to the dashboard you can reinstall Wordpress (this will replace all the critical wordpress files and shouldn't effect your site functionality).  And you can re-download your theme.  There is something that is causing it to not show.  like it is getting stuck somewhere.  Do you have the ability to reboot your server?

Comment: I cannot reboot the server, as it is hosted on a shared machine on godaddy. I am backing up the files and the database, so I can reinstall wordpress free of guilt

Comment: Reinstalling the theme did the trick. Thank you a lot!